# Recording Memory Footprint In Linux

Tags: linux, unix, memory-footprint

Is there a way we can record memory footprint? In a way that 
after the process has finish we still can have access to it.

The typical way I check memory footprint is this:

```
$ cat /proc/PID/status
```

But in no way it exist after the process has finished.

Comment: Similar question on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/11754/running-batch-jobs-and-getting-a-peak-memory-usage-summary-for-each-job/12066

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
watch 'grep VmSize /proc/PID/status >> log'
```

when the program ends you'll have a list of memory footprints over time in `log`.

Comment: @Nathan: thanks. BTW how can I release this command of yours at the same time "together" with my command? Such that it won't be any time lag between the two.

Comment: your best bet is probably to have a wrapper script call the program and then run the command I suggested.  You'll still have a time lag, but it'll be shorter than doing it manually

Answer (score 4):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) has a memory profiler called [Massif](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#massif) that provides detailed information about the memory usage of your program:

> Massif is a heap profiler. It performs detailed heap profiling by taking regular snapshots of a program's heap. It produces a graph showing heap usage over time, including information about which parts of the program are responsible for the most memory allocations. The graph is supplemented by a text or HTML file that includes more information for determining where the most memory is being allocated. Massif runs programs about 20x slower than normal.

Answer (score 2):

You can record it using [munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) + a custom plugin.

This will allow you to monitor and save the needed process information, and graph it, easily.

[Here's a related answer I gave at serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/11550/peak-memory-usage-of-a-process/11562#11562)